# correct way to structure a complex, multi-package SSIS job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I have an SSIS solution that has hundreds of components and approximately 30 packages. **I would like to know what would be the best way to structure such a solution.**

The entire thing looks like this:

[image]

When double clicking on any one of those components, to view the **data flow**, it looks like this:

[image]

As a way to make my work more manageable, I've broken up every individual **control flow component** into its own solution. Another words, I've taken everyone of these:

[image]

and I've created a solution for every one of them:

[image]

Now I need to create a master solution.

[image]

**Question:** How do a structure a "master" solution to run every one of these solutions in a specified order (as specified by the first graphic)?

[image]

Thank you so much for your kind and generous guidance and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your master package as a series of Execute Package Tasks with precedence constraints in the order that you want them to run.  That way you can use package configurations to pass variables to the sub-packages, if that's something you need to do.

[image]

Edit:  To use package configurations to pass the connection string, do the following:

Set a variable in the master package with the connection string as its value.  (Execute Package Task is the sub package).

[image]

In the child package, under SSIS>Package Configurations in the menu, add a parent variable package configuration.

[image]

Then, map that parent variable value to either a variable in the child package, or directly to the appropriate connection string in the child package. (I typically pass it to a sub variable).

[image]

Save the configuration.  Please note that the child package will no longer run independently without being called by the master package.

Comment: You could store the connection string as a variable in the master package, then use a parent package configuration to pass that string to the connection managers of each package for use.  That would allow you to update the string for all subpackages at once.  I don't know if it is possible to actually reuse the same connection manager.